# Lenovo ThinkPad E490 with Xubuntu 18.04 doesn't awake from suspend

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, lenovo, thinkpad

Fresh installed Xubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo E490

After lid-close suspend, laptop cannot wake up. Just black screen. And restart needed.

Any ideas what to try to fix?

Comment: Is this solution useful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176924/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-from-sleep-suspend-lid-closed